# Push properties of an array into two new arrays, using for loop - JS

Tags: javascript

I am doing a online course where I got the following assignment:

```
var peopleArray = [
  {
    name: "Harrison Ford",
    occupation: "Actor"
  },
  {
    name: "Justin Bieber",
    occupation: "Singer"
  },
  {
    name: "Vladimir Putin",
    occupation: "Politician"
  },
  {
    name: "Oprah",
    occupation: "Entertainer"
  }
]
```

Write a loop that pushes the names into a names array, and the occupations into an occupations array.

My question is: How do I write a for loop that pushes the names into a new array that is called Names, and occupations into a new array that is called Occupations? I am using Scrimba, so I will need to console log my results.

Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Before asking others to help with your assignment, please make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Please read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3082296) and [How much effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
// Original
var peopleArray = [
  {
    name: "Harrison Ford",
    occupation: "Actor"
  },
  {
    name: "Justin Bieber",
    occupation: "Singer"
  },
  {
    name: "Vladimir Putin",
    occupation: "Politician"
  },
  {
    name: "Oprah",
    occupation: "Entertainer"
  }
]

// Solution
let namesArray = []
let occupationsArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < peopleArray.length; i++){
  namesArray.push(peopleArray[i].name)
  occupationsArray.push(peopleArray[i].occupation)
}
console.log(namesArray)
console.log(occupationsArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var peopleArray = [
  {
    name: "Harrison Ford",
    occupation: "Actor"
  },
  {
    name: "Justin Bieber",
    occupation: "Singer"
  },
  {
    name: "Vladimir Putin",
    occupation: "Politician"
  },
  {
    name: "Oprah",
    occupation: "Entertainer"
  }
]

const names = []
const occupations = [];

peopleArray.forEach(el => {
    names.push(el.name);
    occupations.push(el.occupation);
});

console.warn(names, occupations);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p1jz2qng/1/

I feel like you are going to assignments too fast. You should learn about arrays before doing that, since this assignment is pretty straightforward if you know anything about arrays.

Comment: Hi. I am doing a course that has gone through arrays and all the basics of JS, HTML and CSS already. I just haven't learned how to push to create new arrays. It's this course: https://scrimba.com/course/gbootcampprimer

I think it's a great course for noobs like myself!